# How do I use Pydantic to validate a dictionary of specific fields of a model?

Tags: python, dictionary, validation, pymongo, pydantic

I'm creating a REST API using PyMongo as the database and Pydantic's BaseModel for data validation, and I'm stuck on figuring out an efficient way to use Pydantic's validation to validate the variable dicts passed to PyMongo's update_one functions. PyMongo's update_one and update_many functions require passing a dict of the fields to update the document itself, meaning that in order to validate them I would either have to create an instance of the model or use TypeAdapter, both of which require all fields to be valid, meaning empty required fields will pop up as errors. I could use default values, or a default User, but that seems messy.

For instance, in my User model, both email and username cannot be None.

```
class User(BaseModel):
    username: str = Field(min_length=1)
    email: EmailStr
```

Say I want to update my e-mail address. PyMongo would want my address to be passed in the following format:

```
newvalues = { "$set": { 'email': "newemail@email.com" } }
```

Using TypeAdapter or creating a User from the dictionary would result in an error as a required field (username) is missing. How do I validate the specific email field without creating a default User or creating validator classes for every field?

Comment: I would use default value in this case:   
```username: Annotated[str, StringConstraints(min_length=1)] = None```

Comment: In that case, how do I cleanly validate that a user isn't being inserted into the database without a username?

Comment: So I didn't quite understand the question correctly. If you need to update your mail, then you must have a username, otherwise how will you understand which user to update it, respectively, you have both fields. If I understand it wrong, please provide a little more code to your question